# How to set a foreign key between two tables with not unique values?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE visits (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    page_id INTEGER(30), 
    user_id INTEGER,
    server_date datetime,
    _source VARCHAR(30)

INSERT INTO visits (page_id, user_id, server_date, _source ) 
VALUES 
(5135611, 10091422, '2017-03-04 23:45:46.000', 'android'  ),
(5135612, 10091422, '2017-03-04 23:46:46.000', 'IOS'  ),    
(5135613, 10091422, '2017-03-05 23:45:46.000', 'android'  ),
(5135614, 10091423, '2017-03-05 23:45:46.000', 'IOS'  ),
(5135615, 10091424, '2017-03-06 23:45:46.000', 'android'  ),
(5135616, 10091425, '2017-03-07 23:45:46.000', 'android'  );

CREATE TABLE Purchases (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    transaction_id INTEGER(30), 
    user_id INTEGER,
    purchase_date  datetime,
    product_type VARCHAR(30),
    price INTEGER   ,
    );

 INSERT INTO Purchases (transaction_id , user_id, purchase_date, product_type, price ) 
VALUES 
(5135611, 10091422, '2017-03-04 23:45:46.000', 'lfl', 150  ),
(5135612, 10091427, '2017-03-04 23:46:46.000', 'sdgw', 2000  ),
(5135613, 10091426, '2017-03-05 23:45:46.000', 'whgwb', 100  ),
(5135614, 10091423, '2017-03-05 23:45:46.000', 'wgwg', 2500  ),
(5135615, 10091424, '2017-03-06 23:45:46.000', 'vas', 2000  ),
(5135616, 10091425, '2017-03-07 23:45:46.000', 'wgw',  300 );*/
```

SO now I'm confused what shoud be the primary keys and foreing keys in these two tables. I thought user_id should be a foreign key for purchases table but the valuses isn't unique there. Don't know how to organize the proper connections.

Comment: Isn't there a Users table? The column user_id in both tables should be a foreign key to the column id of the Users table.

Comment: I think that's reasonable. So in that way these 3 tables could be connected? SO how then to make a query that finds unique users that bought some kind of product?

Comment: Create the table Users and ask a new question where you present all the relevant data. The comments section is not the place to ask new questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate dictionary table. Like this

```
create table users(
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    username varchar(100) not null defaul '',
    primary key(id)
);
```

And refer to this table with foreign keys from your tables.

INT must be unsigned for auto_increment,

int(30) doesn't make sense
the argument indicates the number of digits to be printed, and the int value cannot be greater than 10
just use default